# Got IK error 33 after generating IK solver using planning description configuration wizard

Tags: ros, ik

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

I recently generated the ik solver for my own 6 dofs robot arm using planning description configuration wizard. But when I tried to calculate the ik solution for a definitely feasible pose, I got the error code 33. I checked the rxconsole and it says that ik initial checking fails. Does anyone know what causes the problem? Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47532/got-ik-error-33-after-generating-ik-solver-using-planning-description-configuration-wizard/) by [shuai](https://answers.ros.org/users/3402/shuai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

-33 means IK_LINK_IN_COLLISION. so make sure that at your goal pose your robot does not collide with other objects.
To check the detailed collision information, use the following code:

assuming that you have a variable  planning_environment::CollisionModels* cm_, then you can use:

```
std::vector<arm_navigation_msgs::ContactInformation> contacts;
cm_->getAllCollisionsForState(*state,contacts);
for(int i=0;i<contacts.size();i++)
{
    std::cout<<contacts[i].contact_body_1<<" and "<<contacts[i].contact_body_2
            <<" in collision"<<std::endl;
}
```

---

Originally posted by [yangyangcv](https://answers.ros.org/users/3011/yangyangcv/) with karma: 741 on 2012-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0